# Handle InversifyJS configuration depending on the environment

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

I've been using **InversifyJS** to handle the DI on my typescript server. The point is that I want to inject different implementations on my code depending on the environment.

There's a common scenario where I want to use S3 on production but a local folder while I am developing on my laptop. Since I am using an `interface` to make this communication, an option would be to have two different configuration files with the container information, but it's pretty dirty to load the container on my services with a conditional.

Another option is to have one configuration file but configuring one implementation or another one depending on the environment. Something like this:

```
container.bind<IStorageRepository>(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.STORAGE).to(
    (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'prod') ? S3StorageRepository : LocalFolderStorageRepository
);
```

But I don't like this at all, because if you have three (or more) different environments with different needs, then it becomes a bit crazy.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the meantime...did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I kept the implementation using `process.env.ENVIRONMENT`, I didn't find a cleaner solution.

Comment: have a look at this approach: [how to conditionally load constantValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344789/infersifyjs-how-to-conditionally-load-constantvalue)

Answer (score 0):

In your case the process of choosing the right implementation move out from .to(). You can handle it above. Assign to a link and pass it there.
In my project for such cases. I hide container assembling process into builder functions. In the imperative way you can handle everything.

Comment: Can you provide an example?