# InfersifyJS - how to conditionally load constantValue

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

I am using inversifyJS in my `typescript` +  `NODE.js` application. I have for different environments different configurations:

### Configuration production

```
const CONFIG_PRODUCTION: Object = {
    PATH_TO_STATIC_FILES: '../web/build',
    SECURE_COOKIE: false
};

export default CONFIG_PRODUCTION;
```

### Configuration development

```
const CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT: Object = {
    PATH_TO_STATIC_FILES: 'build/web/build',
    SECURE_COOKIE: true
};

export default CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT;
```

Now on my infersify container configuration my setup looks like this:

### Inversify configuration

```
const dependencyContainer = new Container();
dependencyContainer.bind(TYPES.ENVIRONMENTAL_CONFIG).toDynamicValue(
    (context: interfaces.Context) => context ? CONFIG_PRODUCTION : CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT);
...

export default dependencyContainer;
```

Now where can I decide how  to load the needed config object? In my class I currently inject the property like this:

### Express file

```
constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.ENVIRONMENTAL_CONFIG) private config: Object
) {
    ...
    console.log(config) // prints development config
}
```

Does inversify provide something like a `setContext()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with to solution to bind the property with the `toFactory` method on the dependency container:

```
dependencyContainer.bind(TYPES.ENVIRONMENTAL_CONFIG).toFactory(
    () => (context: interfaces.Context) => context ? CONFIG_PRODUCTION : CONFIG_DEVELOPMENT);
```

after that I inject the Factory as Function in my used class:

```
constructor(@inject(TYPES.ENVIRONMENTAL_CONFIG) private environmentFactory: Function) {
    this.environmentalProps = this.environmentFactory(isProduction);
  }
```